# Capybara select drop down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, factory-bot

I am learning unit testing and I am a little lost when it comes to Capybara's select option. Can someone please explain how I get factory girl to pass this test.

**Project Feature Spec**

```
require 'spec_helper'   
describe 'create project creation' do   

  it 'allows user to create a project' do
    visit projects_path
    click_link 'Create Project'

    fill_in 'Title', with: 'Secklow Sounds'
    fill_in 'Description', with: 'This is the project description'
    select('Jane', :from => 'Client')
    select('Mike', :from => 'Client Assistant')
    select('active', from: 'Status')
    fill_in 'Budget', with: '200'
    fill_in 'Start date', with: '24 January 2013'
    fill_in 'Deadline', with: '24 January 2014'

    click_button 'Create Project'

    expect(page).to have_content('Project was successfully created.')

  end  
end
```

**Factory Girl**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :project do
    title "MyString"
    description "MyText"
    status 1
    budget "9.99"
    user_id 1
    assistant_id 1
    start_date "2014-04-17"
    deadline "2014-04-17"
    slug "MyString"
  end
end
```

My question is how do I get them to work together, at the moment I get an error when running tests

```
Failures:

  1) create project creation allows user to create a project
     Failure/Error: select('Jane', :from => 'Client')
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find option "Jane"
     # ./spec/features/project_feature_spec.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**EDIT**

**My form**

```
= simple_form_for(@project, :defaults => { :wrapper_html => {:class => 'form-group'}, :input_html => { :class => 'form-control', :role => 'form' } }) do |f|

  .form-inputs
    = f.input :title
    = f.input :description
    .row
      .col-md-2
        = f.association :user, label: 'Client'
      .col-md-2
        = f.association :assistant, label: 'Client Assistant'
      .col-md-2
        = f.input :status, collection: %w{ pending active completed suspended funding  }, include_blank: false
      .col-md-2
        %br
        .input-group
          %span.input-group-addon €
          = f.input_field :budget, class: 'form-control', label: true
    .row
      .col-md-2
        = f.input :start_date, as: :string, placeholder: '23 February 2014'
      .col-md-2
        = f.input :deadline, as: :string, placeholder: '16 March 2014'

  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit, class: 'btn'
```

Comment: Can you also provide the view containing the select you're struggling with? According to the error, you have no Jane option available to select.

Comment: I actually do have jane as one of the drop down options, it's a user's name.

Comment: I would try changing your capybara selectors to use the HTML ID of the elements you're trying to control. It's far less ambiguous. 'Client' could refer to either one of your existing select boxes. Try this: `select('Jane', :from => 'project_user_id')` obviously check the source HTML for the correct ID as I'm only guessing.

Comment: no luck :( problem still

Comment: You likely do not have a "Jane" available to select then. Since it's not in the source of the page I assume it's populated from the DB? Remember your seed data wont by default be populated in a test database. Is Jane created by a client factory?